# Android change default browser

Tags: android

Is there a way to change the default browser in an android emulator using some code running outside emulator. We want to change the android device default browser programmatic manner.

Comment: I assume/hope this is not possible: 't is a user choice, and should not be changed by an app, even if it is possible. You should provide instructions on how to do it maybe, but why would an app control what *your* default browser is?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to change the default browser in an android emulator using some code running outside emulator.

That is impossible in two ways.

First, it is impossible for an SDK application to change the default application, other than to make itself *not* be the default.

Second, it is impossible for an Android device to run an Android application that is not on the Android device ("some code running outside emulator").